# Dynamically adding and loading image from Resources in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I have some images added to my solution, right now it is under the folder images\flowers\rose.png inside the solution explorer. I want a way to dynamically load  this image to my image control.

My current approach is making the type 'content' and use 'copy always' properties. Then i would give relative path to the image like below.

```
Image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/flowers/Customswipe_b.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there any way to make it load from the resource without copying it to the target system.

Answer (score 21):

The following works just fine for me:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/Resources/someimage.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Also you should change the `Build Action` of your image from `None` to `Resource`.

Answer (score 8):

You can open the Resource Editor (Solution Explorer, click on Resources.resx) and add the image there. Then you can simply access it as `Bitmap` with `Properties.Resources.ImageId`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 6):

I had some problems to find the exact syntax for the URI, so see below more details :

If your image (`myImage.png`) is located in a subfolder "images" (from the root directory) , the exact syntax is :

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/images/myImage.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

If your image is in the subfolder `images/icon/` (from the root directory) , the syntax is :

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/images/icon/myImage.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

- Note that the part `"pack://application:,,,` does not change.
- Be sure to set the "Build action" to "Resources"

For more information: [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly).