# How to load embebbed resource image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954327/dynamically-adding-and-loading-image-from-resources-in-c-sharp/12955206#12955206) I was able to load the image with the absolute imagepath, but not sure if this works on the client machine after packaging application (.exe)?

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12955206/15569855) quite similar to the way I do it on winform but I am having difficulty getting this Properties from code `(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources)`.

How to declare or access this Properties?

Thanks !